# What's the right way to Load child collections inside a POCO with a SubSonic Repository?

Tags: c#, subsonic, repository-pattern, poco

I've read the questions asking about the right way to inject data access into POCOs, and the consensus seems to be "don't". Fine, what is the right way then? If I have an Order object, and I want a list of the OrderLines, I don't want to explicitly assign that list to the POCO externally, that's horribly ugly. So if I can't use DI to give the POCO a little intelligence, do I need to create a dummy object that can grab the extra information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to establish a [one to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838410/how-to-use-one-to-many-relations-in-subsonic) relationship.

[How to use “one to many” relations in SubSonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838410/how-to-use-one-to-many-relations-in-subsonic)

[How do I setup my POCO’s with Subsonic 3 and the SimpleRepostitory? or where is the convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827630/how-do-i-setup-my-pocos-with-subsonic-3-and-the-simplerepostitory-or-where-is-t)